# jQuery: submit form on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form with a field element when a user clicks a button. I'm using the `change` function, which is called after a file has been chosen. The problem is that the form data is submitted without the field data. How can I make it submit the form after the field data is set?

The below code works fine if I call it with `submit` instead of `change`.

```
<form method="POST" action="public/index.php/students/edit/49" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="fileform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('fileupload').click();  return false;" value="UPLOAD CV / RESUME" class="add" />
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</form>

<script>
$('#fileupload').change(function()
{ 
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: "{{URL::action('StudentController@addDocument')}}",
        data: formData,
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
      console.log( msg );
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      console.log(textStatus );
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `fileupload` element?

Comment: Have you tried adding a name attribute on your file field?

Comment: The argument to `new FormData()` is supposed to be a form, not an input.

Comment: @sotoz: I just tried it, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: @Barmar: It is a form. If I add a submit button and use `submit` instead of `change`, the file data is transferred correctly.

Comment: But do you get the desired effect if you change to 
 $('#fileform').change(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
...
    });

Comment: In the `.change()` handler, `this` is the file input element, not the form. Try using `new FormData(this.form)`.

Comment: @MasterSlave: No, that doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Barmar: That doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$.fn.serializefiles = function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    /* ADD FILE TO PARAM AJAX */
    var formData = new FormData();
    $.each($(obj).find("input[type='file']"), function(i, tag) {
        $.each($(tag)[0].files, function(i, file) {
            formData.append(tag.name, file);
        });
    });
    var params = $(obj).serializeArray();
    $.each(params, function (i, val) {
        formData.append(val.name, val.value);
    });
    return formData;
};
```

then in function ajax

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "{{URL::action('StudentController@addDocument')}}",
    data: $('#fileform').serializefiles(),
});
```

You want to upload a file or some files by ajax, you have to write a function above

Comment: My Ajax file upload works fine as is. The problem is with the `change` function.

Comment: you should using a jquery library for this work. I usually use [Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput). It's simple using.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `$('#fileupload').change( ... )` refers to input element, formData expects a form element, try this:

```
$('#fileupload').change(function () {
    var formData = new FormData(this.form);

    ...

});
```

you also need to add `name` attribute to your file input.

Request then looks like:

```
...
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="FILE_NAME"
Content-Type: CONTENT_TYPE
...
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear enough. The ajax form upload works fine if I use `submit` instead of `change`. Maybe this is due to that when `change` is called, the file has still not been added. I've also tried both your suggestions already and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, it's only `$(this)[0]` that works. When I use `this.form` with `submit`, it does not work.

Comment: @dan-klasson How about just calling `this.form.submit()` from your `change`?